# Citing information from table in a review paper

Tags: citations

in a review paper, there is a topic which I need so much, the Author reviews information from sources A, B, C and D. Then he summarizes it in a table. my question is can I cite information from the table and refer to the author as the source of information or should I go to the original sources and cite from ?? Note: the table has no references.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not clear.

To make life easiest on your readers, cite the review paper. Then they can find everything in one place.

You should try to track down the original sources just to check that the review paper is correct - particularly since you need that material "so much" and the review paper has no references. You may then want to cite those sources too, depending on what you find there that's not in the review paper. If you can't find an original source you should probably say so.